# laravel route variables passing null values give url error

Tags: php, laravel, routes, optional-variables

I have a route that **has 3 optional** variables declared as null in Controller

```
Route::get('gegonota/{gid?}/{cid?}/{nid?}', [
'uses' => 'GegonosController@index', 
'as' => 'gegonota'
]);
```

and **even i change the order of the parameter the problem still exists.**

```
public function index($gid = null, $cid = null, $nid = null)
```

When values of the variables are null are not showing in the url like

```
http://localhost:8000/gegonota///1
```

and gives me route errors like it didnt find the specific url.

I have to check and substitute null to 0 so that has something in the url and  give no error.
Which is laravel way to do that avoiding all the trouble.
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846688/laravel-4-optional-parameter)

Comment: Yeah, you can't use path params like that. The optional params have to be at the end of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in using [Optional Path Parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) as stated in Laravel doc. This means you'll have:

```
Route::get('gegonota/{gid}/{cid}/{nid?}', [
    'uses' => 'GegonosController@index', 
    'as' => 'gegonota'
]);
```

Hope this solves the issue.

**Update**

Even though I cannot say this is the fix since you said rearranging the variable did not solve the issue. I would rather pass those optional variables as request parameters to make things easy, i.e my url would look like:

```
http://localhost:8000/gegonota/?gid=&cid=&nid=
```

Therefore, I can already set the default for each of the expected parameters as null rather than deal with inconsistency that may arise from having this kind of wierd `///` in my url:

```
//In a controller
public funtion index()
{
    //put them in an array
    $my_variables = request()->only(['gid', 'cid', 'nid']);

    //or this way
    $gid = request()->get('gid');
    $cid = request()->get('cid');
    $nid = request()->get('nid');

   //they are default to null if not existing or have no value
}
```

This means your route declaration is simple, i.e:

```
Route::get('gegonota', [
    'uses' => 'GegonosController@index', 
    'as' => 'gegonota'
```

])

Unless there is an **exceptional** need to pass those optional variable to the path, its clearly easier and better to have it as request parameters.
Hope this is better.

Comment: Its my mistake i did used ? in parameteres in route this is the right code i wrote
    Route::get('gegonota/{gid?}/{cid?}/{nid?}', [
    'uses' => 'GegonosController@index', 
    'as' => 'gegonota'
]);

Comment: my question is similar to another with optional parameters but i have 3 parameters and even if i change the order of them if the first or the second are null the url gives errors.

Comment: i use parameters to pass values for filters. Maybe its not the right way to do that

Comment: @gaspriceadmin check the updated answer. I would rather that you use request parameter rather than path variable in this case then.

Comment: Yes this is the right way i believe now. 
Thank you @Omisakin